# Attempting to upload file to AWS S3 but file is corrupt

Tags: rest-api, aws, amazon-s3, sharepoint, amazon-aws

I am attempting to download a file from SharePoint through their Rest API, and then upload that file to my S3 Bucket. I can "successfully" download the file and upload to S3. The issue is when I then go to my bucket and look at the file it's corrupted.

My code:

```
public static void uploadFile() {
        AccessTokenResponse accessToken = getAccessToken();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('<Sharepoint path>/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl=\'/sites/<channelname>/Shared%20Documents/General/TestFile.docx\')//OpenBinaryStream()');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken.access_token);
        Http h = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
        uploadToAWS(res.getBody());
}

public static void uploadToAWS(String body) {
       Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf(body);
        String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bodyBlob);
        String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
        String key = '<key>';
        String secret = '<secret>';
        String bucketname = '<bucket name>';
        String host = 's3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
        String method = 'PUT';
        String filename = 'TestFile.docx';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + bucketname + '.' + host + '/' + filename);
        req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
        req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
        req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
        req.setBodyAsBlob(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody));

        String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\napplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\n' + formattedDateString + '\n' + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename;
        String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(secret));
        String signedKey  = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
        String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signedKey ;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

I can go to my bucket in S3 and see that a file was uploaded by that name. When I download the file and try to open it though it says its corrupted. I'm not sure how to debug anymore.

I've tried with both a docx and a pdf, with the same corrupted result.

Any idea on why my file is corrupted, or either what I should be doing to fix it or how I can debug more to understand where things are failing?

Comment: Can you share the "corrupt" file link? Someone like me could look at it and fairly immediately tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @sfdcfox, that would be awesome! I can't paste the link here because the presigned url is too long. Is there an email or other way I can send you the link?

Comment: My contact info is on my profile if you desire.

Comment: Found it! Sent you the link in a private message on twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I took a look at the file in a Text editor, and it started off with PK. So far, so good. I then took a look at the file through a hex editor, and saw it started with 50 4b 03 04, which are the "magic bytes" for a ZIP file (DOCX is fundamentally a ZIP file). However, I then tried to verify the contents:

```
unzip -t TestFile.docx
```

And I got the following output:

```
Archive:  TestFile.docx

caution:  zipfile comment truncated
error [TestFile.docx]:  missing 3316400188 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [TestFile.docx]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

In other words, some of the bytes got messed up. That's when I realized you used the wrong method in your Apex code:

```
    // ...
    uploadToAWS(res.getBody());
}
public static void uploadToAWS(String body) {
```

Here, you call getBody(), which returns a UTF-8 string. I'm kind of surprised you didn't get an invalid UTF-8 StringException, but this definitely changed some of the bytes. To fix it, get the body as a blob:

```
    // ...
    uploadToAWS(res.getBodyAsBlob());
}
public static void uploadToAWS(Blob body) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That fixed my issue!